# How i get jest coverage with coverage folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, code-coverage

When i run jest coverage it do the coverage successfully but i dont get coverage folder with all details. I get only coverage folder with coverage-final.json file inside it. and i get this error

Failed to write coverage reports:

> ERROR: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open
> 'D:\Programing\Wep\Development\Node Js\coverage\lcov.info'

my scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config jestconfig.json",
    "test:coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage"
  }
```

and jest config is

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/) (test|spec))\\.(js?|ts?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "js"]
}
```

I expext to get coverage folder with all detailes inside it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add theses properties into your jest config file

```
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageReporters": ["json", "html"]
```